# PIC32MX795F512H + DP83822I Transmit Error Signal

Tags: microchip, poe

I am using [PIC32MX795F512H](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/60001156J.pdf) with [DP83822I](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/dp83822i.pdf)  as the Ethernet PHY transceiver. On the PIC32MX there is a pin for Transmit Error (ETXERR) but no Transmit Error pin on DP83822I. What should I do with the ETXERR pin since I can't connect it to to the DP83822I?

Comment: Does the PIC Users Manual have a recommendation?

Comment: I did a search through the PIC datasheet but didn't see a recommendation.

Comment: Maybe I am confused here (or out of my SME), but how do you intend on handling TX Errors (from the PIC)? And what are you using to drive the RX_ER (on the TI)?

Comment: The PIC has a ERXERR signal for the RX_ER signal on the TI